# Как устранить ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._metrics'?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
>>>>
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
>>>>



>>>>
выдает ошибку '     from kivy._metrics import dpi2px, NUMERIC_FORMATS, 
dispatch_pixel_scale, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._metrics'
Помогите решить проблему
```

Comment: Установить модуль, не?

Comment: а как? кучу всего поставил